# InvalidCastException with Constructor Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I got a service using constructor dependecy injection.
In the constructor i try to differ between two types.
Depending on the result i want to cast the interface to one of it's implementations.
here's the constructor:

```
private readonly IControlService _syncService;

    public CacheService(IControlService syncService)
    {

        if (Config.Config.type == ControlType.Type1) 
        {
            try
            {
                _syncService = (type1Service)syncService;
            }
            catch (Exception e) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }
        }
        else if (Config.Config.type == ControlType.Type2)
        {

            _syncService = (type2Service)syncService;
        }  
    }
```

Both - type1Service and type2Service implement the interface IControlService.
However, if control type ist Type1, i'm getting

```
03-25 12:38:15.503 I/mono-stdout( 2542): System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
```

Type2 works well. Any Ideas?

Comment: The code you show looks fine. Have you done a full rebuild? No old static references somewhere or something similar? If you debugg and inspect syncService you dont see anything wrong or strange?

Comment: I've done all that.
Guess, the Problem is something with MvvmCross ioc and the double implementation of the interface.

Comment: I've not used that one, but I've used others without problems in smilar situations (autofac was my latest ioc I tried) , would be weird if that would be an issue but perhaps you should post that code and someone might see something.

Comment: How are you telling the IoC container which `IControlService` to create? Can you edit the question to include your IoC registration code - I guess this also switches on `Config.Config.type` somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help!

Problem was in the app.cs and the IoC registration Code like Stuart assumed.
I renamed the two Implementation Classes and removed the 'Service' ending.
So the Code now casts like this:

`_syncService = (Type1)syncService;`

and the Registration looks like that:

```
public override void Initialize()
    {
        CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Service")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

        if(Config.Config.type == ControlType.Type1)
        {
            Mvx.RegisterType<IControlService, Type1>();
        }
        else if (Config.Config.type == ControlType.Type2)
        {
            Mvx.RegisterType<IControlService, Type2>();
        }

        RegisterAppStart<ViewModels.FirstViewModel>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the IoC container is passing in correct type? What happens with this code?

```
    if (Config.Config.type == ControlType.Type1) 
    {
        var s = syncService as type1Service;

        if (s == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException (
                string.Format ("Expected type: {0}, Actual type: {1}", 
                    typeof(type1Service), 
                    syncService.GetType ()));
        }
    }
```